# Angular 13 loading JSON file with HTTP Get

Tags: json, angular, typescript, http

i try to get some JSON Data from a local file in assets. I search with google and found different solutions, but nothing is working, like i want.

i add a service with follow code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class JSONService {
    public JSONArr: any;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient ) { }

    initJSON(path: string = "") { 
        this.JSONArr = this.getJSONArr(path);
        
        console.log("@ Service");
        console.log(path);
        console.log(this.JSONArr);
        // return this.JSONArr;
    }

    async getJSONArr( path: string = ""): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(path).subscribe(data => { 
            this.JSONArr = data;
            console.log(data);
        }
    }

    
}
```

the path is given from the app.component.ts
the JSON look as follow

```
{
        "title": "Testtitle",
        "content": "Test Message"
}
```

My problem is:
the console.log within the **getJSONArr** returns the data from the json correctly,
but the console.log within the **initJSON** returns **undefined**

can anyone help me ?

Comment: simply put: in your code, `getJSONArr` returns a subscription

Answer (score 2):

You do the wrong way there. because an HTTP request is `async`. So, your console.log will show `undefined` for `this.JSONArr`.

in your service, you can only:

```
async getJSONArr(path: string = ""): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.get(path);
}
```

and in your component, you need only subscribe method to get data from JSON file

Component.ts

```js
this.yourService.getJSONArr(yourPath).subscribe((jsonData) => console.log(jsonData));
```